# Reading specific value from a text file

Tags: php

I am trying to read a specific value from a text file. My text file looks like this:

```
token = 12345
data = new
...
```

I want to capture the value of a token. My php is as follows:

```
$myFile = "../data/input.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
echo $lines[0]; //line 1
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$lines[0]);
```

The output is

> token = 12345

but I want to capture just **12345**.
After capturing the number , i am planning to use it in the path..but its giving aspace before the number.please go through the code below and let me know, if you have any suggestions.

```
$myFile = "../data/input.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
list($token, $number) = explode('=', $lines[0]);
$dir = "C:/wamp/.../$number/Profit/Jan2010";
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
 while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
   echo "<a href=".$dir."/".$file.">$file</a><br/>";
  }
 }
closedir($handle);
```

My path should be .../12345/Profit/Jan2010.
By using the above code , i am getting ..../ 12345/Profit/Jan2010  (a space before 12345).
Can i use $number in the path?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're echoing before the preg replace. Have you tried echoing the preg replace or assigning it to $lines[0]? `$lines[0] =  preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$lines[0]); echo $lines[0];`

Comment: just echo preg_replace return http://stackoverflow.com/a/18966397/2459296

Comment: You might also look into using the [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) method, rather than regex if your file format is similar in structure to php.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're not using the output of `preg_replace` properly.

The number is actually getting stored in `$lines[0];` but you're just echoing it instead of storing it in a variable.

The following should work:

```
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$lines[0]);
echo $number;
```

Alternatively, you could also use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) (might be a bit more efficient some cases)  to split your string by a delimiter:

```
list($token,  $number) = explode('=', $lines[0]);
echo (int) $number;
```

**UPDATE**

> My path should be .../12345/Profit/Jan2010. By using the above code , i am getting ..../ 12345/Profit/Jan2010 (a space before 12345).

That's probably because of the whitespace in `$number`. To remove that, you can use [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) as follows:

```
$number = trim($number);
```

Or, include a space in your delimiter:

```
list($token, $number) = explode(' = ', $lines[0]);
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/1AxKvrOS)

Comment: Just for cleanliness, I would recommend casting the number as an `int`. It will remove extraneous whitespace and ensure it's the correct datatype for this context.

Comment: @SamT: Good idea. Updated.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I can guess why. The OP already had functional code. He was just not assigning it or echoing it. In short, he was not using the preg_replace. Your answer works but is curiously deviant considering what OP posted. All he has to do is echo the preg replace he already has or assign it to a var and echo that. And seeing your update I give you a plus.

Comment: @KaiQing: Yeah, I misread the question first and have updated the answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

It should show only 12345 which you have already used

Just use echo before your last line

```
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$lines[0]);
```